# can't find the executable for the command linux 'source'

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, shell, command

i am using ubuntu server 12.04 lts. I am looking for the executable of the linux command `source` i can not find in the /bin nor /usr/bin nor /usr/sbin nor /usr/local/bin . I used `whereis source` it gives me `source:` but i need the path for this command.
does any one know where to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not find the binary executable, because `source` is a built-in Bash command. Why would you need the binary anyway?

Comment: i am using puppet and i need to execute the source command. as i know i can't execute built-in Bash command in puppet.

Comment: @user2281794: What do you try to accomplish with the `source` anyway? If you execute a shell command in puppet, it will run in a child process and any variable you set will be lost upon exit.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

> Builtin commands are contained within the shell itself

Thus as Erathiel said before, you won't find it.